# How to convert datetime to year wise like aug 2014 to july 2015 in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have datetime like  `2014-11-05 00:00:00` which lies in the year of 2015 to 2016.
I have to represent this to `Aug 2014 to Jul 2015` format

Comment: see this link : http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime 
its may help

Comment: how is `2014-11-05` Aug or July?

Comment: @Vedprakash Singh what you want to do exactly?

Comment: i want to convert datetime to acedmic year . for eg. i have the datetime '2014-11-05 00:00:00 ' and i want it converted to period 'Aug 2014 '  to July2015'

Comment: `2014-11-05` this date you want as Nov 2014?

Comment: 2014-11-05  as this date is fall in between period Aug 2014 to July2015. i want it converted into academic year which start from 'Aug '  and end on july

Comment: @VedprakashSingh please edit your question and provide more details. Mentioning "academic year" would probably help to understand your problem. Also keep in mind that academic years are handled differently across the globe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
t = Time.now
#=> 2015-07-15 12:55:26 +0530
if t.strftime("%m").to_i < 8
  puts "Aug #{t.strftime('%Y').to_i - 1} to July #{t.strftime('%Y')}"
else
  puts "Aug #{t.strftime('%Y')} to July #{t.strftime('%Y').to_i + 1}"
end
#=> Aug 2014 to July 2015
```

As you mention in comment that academic year which start from `Aug` and end on `July` so as per today's date it will display `Aug 2014 to July 2015`

As [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423485/how-to-convert-datetime-to-year-wise-like-aug-2014-to-july-2015-in-ruby#comment-50819823) has mention in comment, you can try this too for easy understanding and clean way(without `strftime`):

```
t = Time.now
if t.month < 8
  puts "Aug #{t.year - 1} to July #{t.year}"
else
  puts "Aug #{t.year} to July #{t.year + 1}"
end
```

Comment: Is there any other inbuilt method in Ruby date for this functionality

Comment: @VedprakashSingh there are different definitions in globe for the academic year so there is no as such any in built method for this

Comment: You can use `t.month` and `t.year` instead of `t.strftime("%m").to_i` and `t.strftime('%Y').to_i`.

Comment: @Stefan : Oh yes thanks for the point. I update my answer.. as always from you many things have to learn. Thanks again